# I got this error (segyread: format not SEGY standard (1, 2, 3, 5, or 8)) while converting from segy to su format on seismic unix

Tags: geophysics

[ ~/Desktop/demo ] $ segyread tape=data.sgy| segyclean>data.su

segyread: format not SEGY standard (1, 2, 3, 5, or 8)

segyclean: fgettr.c: bad first header
[ ~/Desktop/demo ] $ 3200+0 records in
6+1 records out
3200 bytes (3.2 kB) copied, 0.00177647 s, 1.8 MB/s

Comment: The error message is saying that according to segyclean,  data.sgy isn't in proper SEG-Y format.  Where did you get the data file?  Can you read the same file with other software?  Can you read other SEG-Y files with segyread?    Do you have a big-/little- endian issue?  Have you tried verbatim=1 with segyread to get more information about the data file?